# Как правильно работать с структурой в стеке?

Tags: c++

Есть стек:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert> // для assert

namespace Program
{
    class Stack
    {
    private:
        struct Shop
        {
            int number; // Номер
            char name[500]; // Название
            char FullName[300]; // Фамилия И.О. директора
            int NumberEmployees; // Кол-во сотрудников
            long int AnnualIncome; // Годовой доход
        };
        Shop *ptr;
        int size; // Максимальное количество элементов в стеке
        int top; // Номер текущего элемента стека
    public:
        Stack(int number)
        {
            size = 20;
            top = 0;
            if (number <= size)
            {
                ptr = new Shop[number];
                size = number;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nПереполнение стека!\n";
            }
        }
        // деструктор
        ~Stack()
        {
            delete[] ptr;
        }

        bool Push(struct Shop pony)
        {
            if (top == size)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr[top].number = pony.number;
                for (int f = 0; ptr[top].name[f] != '\0'; f++)
                {
                    ptr[top].name[f] = pony.name[f];
                }
                for (int f = 0; ptr[top].FullName[f] != '\0'; f++)
                {
                    ptr[top].FullName[f] = pony.FullName[f];
                }
                ptr[top].NumberEmployees = pony.NumberEmployees;
                ptr[top].AnnualIncome = pony.AnnualIncome;
                top++;
                return true;

            }
        }

        Shop Pop()
        {
            assert(top > 0); // номер текущего элемента должен быть больше 0
            ptr[--top];
        }

        bool Is_empty()
        {
            if (top < 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool Is_full()
        {
            if (top == size)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

И сам код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "class.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
using Program::Stack;

struct Shop
{
    int number; // Номер
    char name[500]; // Название
    char FullName[300]; // Фамилия И.О. директора
    int NumberEmployees; // Кол-во сотрудников
    long int AnnualIncome; // Годовой доход
} pony;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

        Stack shp = 2;
        for (int i = 0; !shp.Is_full(); i++)
        {
            cout << "Номер: ";
            cin >> pony.number;
            cout << "Название: ";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(pony.name, 500);
            cout << "Фамилия И.О. директора: ";
            cin.getline(pony.FullName, 300);
            cout << "Кол-во сотрудников: ";
            cin >> pony.NumberEmployees;
            cout << "Годовой доход: ";
            cin >> pony.AnnualIncome;
            shp.Push(pony);
        }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

И есть вот такая ошибка. В чём моя проблема и как её исправить?
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Вы можете скопировать код, приведённый в скриншоте, и вставить его в вопрос в виде текста. Строку, в которой возникла ошибка, можно пометить комментарием в коде.

Comment: У вас ошибка в процедуре `Shop Pop()`: вы ничего не возвращаете. Это неправильно (даже если это случайно как-то работает) и может привести к «невозможным» ошибкам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что структуры `Shop` в вашей программе и `Shop` в файле класса разные. `Shop` в файле класса на самом деле находится в `namespace Program` в `private` зоне класса `Stack`. И вы не можете заменить эту структуру на ту, что вы объявили в своей программе. Первое, что приходит в голову - написать в программе

```
Stack::Shop pony;
```

Вместо объявления новой структуры, но это повлечет за собой ошибку - `Shop` находится в `private` зоне класса `Stack`, никто, кроме самого класса, туда доступ не имеет. Решение такое: переместите объявление `Shop` в `public` зону вашего класса, тогда указанное выше исправление будет работать.
Я бы сделал так: так как класс `Stack` может использоваться в других контекстах, нет особого смысла привязывать к нему `Shop`, поэтому просто перенесите его за пределы класса, но оставьте в `namespace Program`. Код будет такой:

```
namespace Program
{
    struct Shop
    {
        int number; // Номер
        char name[500]; // Название
        char FullName[300]; // Фамилия И.О. директора
        int NumberEmployees; // Кол-во сотрудников
        long int AnnualIncome; // Годовой доход
    };
    class Stack
    {
    private:
        Shop *ptr;
        int size; // Максимальное количество элементов в стеке
        int top; // Номер текущего элемента стека
    public:
        Stack(int number)
        {
            size = 20;
            top = 0;
            if (number <= size)
            {
                ptr = new Shop[number];
                size = number;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "\nПереполнение стека!\n";
            }
        }
        // деструктор
        ~Stack()
        {
            delete[] ptr;
        }

        bool Push(struct Shop pony)
        {
            if (top == size)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr[top].number = pony.number;
                for (int f = 0; ptr[top].name[f] != '\0'; f++)
                {
                    ptr[top].name[f] = pony.name[f];
                }
                for (int f = 0; ptr[top].FullName[f] != '\0'; f++)
                {
                    ptr[top].FullName[f] = pony.FullName[f];
                }
                ptr[top].NumberEmployees = pony.NumberEmployees;
                ptr[top].AnnualIncome = pony.AnnualIncome;
                top++;
                return true;

            }
        }

        Shop Pop()
        {
            assert(top > 0); // номер текущего элемента должен быть больше 0
            ptr[--top];
        }

        bool Is_empty()
        {
            if (top < 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool Is_full()
        {
            if (top == size)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

После этого допишите `using Program::Shop;` и объявляйте свою пони как `Shop pony;`. Такие дела.